# Correct name for terminal block for ring crimp terminated wires

Tags: connector

Does anyone know what this is called?

[image]

Answer (score 7):

A ["stud junction block"](https://www.google.com/search?q=stud+junction+block&tbm=isch&source=lnms).

For example:

https://wiringproducts.com/products/stud-junction-block

https://www.ionnic.com/electrical/connectors/junction-blocks/multiple-stud.html

Answer (score 5):

Single row terminal block or barrier block.

Comment: [Single row terminal block](https://www.google.com/search?q=single+row+terminal+block&tbm=isch), and [barrier block](https://www.google.com/search?q=barrier+block&tbm=isch) are more generic terms. A more specific term is ["junction block"](https://www.google.com/search?q=stud+junction+block&tbm=isch).

Answer (score 4):

A single row terminal block (or terminal strip) with barriers.

It's more common to see those with screws, to accept spade terminals or bare wires; the one in your photo looks like it has a nut-and-bolt arrangement to accept ring terminals.

Comment: Those are more generic terms that point OP to types of products other than what OP has there: [terminal block](https://www.google.com/search?q=terminal+block&tbm=isch), and [terminal strip](https://www.google.com/search?q=terminal+strip&tbm=isch). A more specific term is ["junction block"](https://www.google.com/search?q=stud+junction+block&tbm=isch).